# Linear algebra of finite abelian groups

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, finite-groups, modules, abelian-groups

Let $\phi:G \to H$ be a surjective homomorphism of finite abelian groups, and

let $g_1, \ldots, g_n$ <strike>be an irredundant set of generators (from now on, a basis) for $G$.</strike> be a basis for $G$, meaning a set of elements with the property that $\langle g_1 \rangle \oplus \ldots \oplus \langle g_n \rangle=G$ (note they have to be in direct sum).

To any basis $h_1, \ldots, h_k$ for $H$, we can associate a matrix $a$ with entries in $\mathbb{Z}$ representing $\phi$, defined by $\phi(g_i)= \sum_{j=1}^k a_{i j} h_j$.

I would like to prove the following statement. Up to permuting the $g_i$'s, we can find **a basis for $H$** (see above) such that the left lower triangle of the associated matrix $a$ is made of ones on the diagonal and zeroes elsewhere. (In the previous sentence, I am assuming that the length of the basis for $H$ must satisfy $k \leq n$). More precisely, such that $a_{n-k+ i, i}=1$ and $a_{n-k+j,i}=0$ for $j>i$.

Do you know of a good reference for this kind of elementary problems? Namely, linear algebra among finite, or finitely generated, abelian groups?

Comment: Do you consider $\{2,3\}$ to be a non-redundant set of generators of $(\mathbf Z/6\mathbf Z,{+})$?

Comment: And what if the images of all the $g_i$ are the same?

Comment: Yes, for me irredundant means minimal, not necessarily of minimal cardinality.

Comment: Do you mean in the case when $H$ is cyclic? In that case the statement seems easy to me.

Comment: @calc: does that mean you consider $\{2, 3\}$ to be a non-redundant set of generators for $(\mathbf{Z}, +)$?

Comment: (update) yes, {2,3} is both non-redundant and a basis for $\mathbb{Z}/6 \mathbb{Z}$. It is not a basis for $\mathbb{Z}$ since $6 \in (2) \cap (3)$.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question (which seems to be the most difficult part) the following simple procedure provides a positive answer, without requiring any group theory. Take the sequence of $g_i$ and while possible eject any element whose image can be expressed in terms of the images of the other (non-ejected) elements. When this terminates, you're left with a sequence of elements whose images generate $H$, and such that removing any one of them would destroy this property. But then these images are by definition a non-redundant sequence of generators of $H$, and can be chosen as the $h_i$. On the $G$ side, tack all ejected elements to the end of the sequence of non-ejected ones. Note that this makes the initial part of the matrix equal to an identity matrix, better than what you asked for.

Comment: You are right. My question was silly. Thanks and sorry.

Comment: I have fixed my question with a different notion of "basis" for a finite abelian group. Sorry it took me so long. This is the question I really meant to ask. Does this make more sense to you?

Comment: (To be more explicit, your answer is no longer valid because the set of generators you produce for $H$ is an irredundant set of generators, but not a basis)